# How to cut a spherical hole in a dome properly

Tags: modifiers, topology

I'm trying to figure out how to put this robot head onto its body. I'll attach pictures, the head goes inside a spherical socket on the upper dome part of the body. I have tried using boolean but it messes up the topology and I want to make sure I am doing this correctly. My last attempt involved using a lower vertex count head to line up with the dome but it was taking far too long. Here are all the attached photos, please let me know if you need more information. I did my best to make this digestible. Thank you so much, blender is quite hard to learn without a teacher :)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ2I3.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create 2 *UV Spheres*, the big with one 16 segments and 8 rings, the small with 12 segments and 6 rings, rotate a bit the small one:

[image]

Use the *Boolean* modifier or the *Boolean* tool so that the 2 spheres merge, give it a nice topology (use join, dissolve vertices, knife tool):

[image]

I seems to work:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I actually wanted to cut a hole in the dome but your method worked with that as well. Is there any specific ratio/science to follow when combining these shapes? I notice that both have a 2:1 segments:rings ratio

Comment: no, well I guess to have a nice and easy topology it's better to work with square quads and not too stretched quads. Also at first I duplicated my 16/8 sphere but I realized that it would make the bridge between the 2 spheres more complicated so I ended up with a 16/8 and a 12/6. Actually I tried several solutions, sometimes things that look easy are not ah ah